# Numerical Hessian for n-Dimensional arguments in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, calculus, derivative

The example is based on an example in Shumway and Stoffer's: "Time Series Analysis and it's Applications with R Examples". In the original example phi, cq, and cr were scalar so the authors could use fdHess without any issues (see the hashed out version of the code).

```
 para=list(phi, cq, cr)
 Linn=function(para){# to evaluate likelhood at estimates
 #kf=Kfilter0(num,y,1,mu0,Sigma0,para[1],para[2],para[3])
 kf=Kfilter0(num,y,A=h,mu0,Sigma0,para[[1]],para[[2]],para[[3]])
 return(kf$like)}
 emhess=fdHess(para, function(para) Linn(para))
 SE=sqrt(diag(solve(emhess$Hessian)))
```

I would like to generalize the code so that it can be applied to multivariate time series models. So in the code shown phi, cq, and cr are n*n arrays.

Is there a package that can calculate the Hessian for a scalar valued function with matrix arguments?

The closest match I can find is this (I also looked at nlme and numDeriv):

[calculating the Gradient and the Hessian in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189900/calculating-the-gradient-and-the-hessian-in-r)

In this case all the arguments are passed as a vector so the function being called has to be modified so that it can take the list of arguments and reconstruct the required matrices.

Is there a method that would allow me to calculate the Hessian for a scalar valued function with matrix arguments without changing the function being called? Seems this would be such a common problem that there would be an off the shelf answer but I haven't been able to find one.

Baz